# C# run cmd command with backslah inside

Tags: c#, cmd

I am having a really bad time with this job. I am trying to execute cmd command from a windows application in c#. The problem is some of the cmd have '\' inside, and given that C# do weird manipulation about backslash ("\" --> "\"), the command with backslash is not working at all.

Here's my code : (pretty simple)

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\\\MIS-L-ITTECH238 /n\\\\srvrosettastone\\MIS-P-SO";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Here's the original cmd command :

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\MIS-L-ITTECH238 /n\\srvrosettastone\MIS-P-SO
```

It look like the cmdtext is interpreted like it is construct in the string(with all backslash doubled)

Comment: try using an @ before the stirng like so: `string text = @"rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\MIS-L-ITTECH238 /n\\srvrosettastone\MIS-P-SO"`

Comment: Define "not working at all". Your `\ ` substitution is correct (and it's **not** weird, it's quite common for `\ ` to be a special character in strings), so something else is wrong. Also you can use the `@` specifier to use [*verbatim string*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

its easier to make it a non-interpreted string by adding the @ sign in front

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText =@"rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\MIS-L-ITTECH238 /n\\srvrosettastone\MIS-P-SO"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

that should do it for you.